# SSH JumpProxy not working for a HPC computing node

Tags: linux, ssh, cluster-computing, openssh

`ssh -J user@loginnode.xx.xx computenode` does not work for my computing node even though both `ssh user@login.xx.xx` on my M1 MAC and `ssh computenode` on loginnode work. It will ask for my login password to HPC, and then there should be a 2-step verification code, but it just shows `Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535` which is not a very helpful error code.

I tried several things to debug:

1. Add public key to the authorized_key at remote loginnode trying to avoid identification. But it still needs typing password. However I won't need to type again if any other window already connected, so I stopped trying.
2. Use `-vvv` option to check which identification file it needs to run `ssh computenode` from the loginnode. I found a key type which cannot be found in `/.ssh` folder at loginnode. So I generated key pairs for that type again and copied it to my personal MAC. I know it's a stupid move and it is still not working.

Could anyone help with debugging this issue? After the proxyjump code works, I want to translate it into config file and use VSCode to access my computenode to run jupyter in VSCode. I succeeded in other no 2-step-verification clusters before, using `-J` option, but I really got stuck in this cluster.